# Self-referential generic member variables in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, generics

Given the following:

```
Public MustInherit Class A(Of X As A(Of X, Y), Y As B(Of X, Y))
End Class

Public MustInherit Class B(Of X As A(Of X, Y), Y As B(Of X, Y))
End Class

Public Class D

    Private _v As A(Of X As A(Of X, Y), Y AS B(Of X, Y))        

    Public Sub Initialize(Of X As A(Of X, Y), Y As B(Of X, Y))(ByVal v As A(Of X, Y))
        _v = v
    End Sub

End Class
```

Is it possible to define the member variable _v? The "As" keyword doesn't seem to be available when defining a member variable, so the above won't compile and the compiler complains that there are too few type parameters.

Comment: As implied (but maybe not explicit enough) in Jared’s answer, the problem here isn’t the self-referentiality. It’s that a *variable* cannot be generic, only a class (or a method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `As` in generic type parameters is establishing a constraint.  This can only be done at the point where a type parameter is defined.  In the case of `_v` you are declaring an instance of a particular type, possibly using existing type parameters.  `As` isn't legal at this point because you aren't defining new type parameters.

You to define the parameters on `D` and use them in the declaration of `_v`

Comment: In other words, it's not possible to define the member variable `_v` as an instance of class `A` without defining additional constraints on `A` through class `D`, even through the essential constraints are already defined in class `A`'s definition? Nor, I take it, could you do so on a class defined as `Public Class A(Of X As C, Y As B(Of X))`?